# 7 Unable to use file_usage_add when adding new content (node id doesn't yet exist)

Tags: files

I have a custom widget with custom field definitions. I am using `hook_widget_form` to create my fields, and I am attached a custom validation function using the `#element_validate` property on a fieldset wrapper to my custom fields. Everything is working as intended, especially when updating existing nodes; however, when creating new nodes I am running into a two-pronged problem when it comes to having images in my custom fields.

I am using `file_usage_add` to bind images to the node, but this creates a problem when adding a new node as the `nid` does not yet appear available in the validation stage of saving (as expected). In these instances, I've used a condition to skip the `file_usage_add` call, but that leads me to a new error (The file used in Masthead Image field may not be referenced). Below is a simplified version of what I'm attempting:

```
function hook_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
    // Setting switch into parameters that wll work widget types that are in module.
    $widget = $element;
    $widget['#delta'] = $delta;
    switch ($instance['widget']['type']) {
        case 'my_widget_type':
            $widget += array(
                '#type' => 'fieldset',
                '#title' => t('Masthead'),
                '#element_validate' => array('_module_widget_validate')
            );

            $widget['imagefid'] = array(
                '#type' => 'managed_file',
                '#title' => t('Masthead Image'),
                '#description' => t('The main image to appear for this masthead.'),
                '#default_value' => $values['imagefid'],
                '#upload_location' => 'public://module_name/',
                '#upload_validators' => array(
                    'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
                )
            );

            $element['my_widget_type'] = $widget;
            break;
    }

    return $element;
}

function _module_widget_validate($element, &$form_state) {
    $delta = $element['#delta'];
    $field = $form_state['field'][$element['#field_name']][$element['#language']]['field'];
    $field_name = $field['field_name'];
    if (isset($form_state['values'][$field_name][$element['#language']][$delta]['my_widget_type'])) {
        $my_fields = $form_state['values'][$field_name][$element['#language']][$delta];
        $values = $my_fields['my_widget_type'];

        if ($values['imagefid']) {
            $file = file_load($values['imagefid']);
            $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
            file_save($file);
            if (isset($element['#entity']->nid) && $element['#entity']->nid > 0) {
                file_usage_add($file, 'module_name', 'node', $element['#entity']->nid);
            }
            $values['imagefid'] = $file->fid;
        }

        form_set_value($element, json_encode($values), $form_state);
    }
}
```

Please assume everything is working except what I'm trying to do with file_usage_add. I realize there may be some aspects that are unconventional (such as the json encoding), but for the requirements of this project, everything is working as intended except in the case of creating new content.

Based on what I've been able to research, a possible alternative approach would be to use `file_usage_add` with the `fid` of the file and changing `node` to `file`, but I feel like this approach would be incorrect. I have also explored adding a `hook_form_submit` to process the image after validation, but this seems to be an approach that would be disconnected from my widget.

Comment: I can get what I need to work by binding the image to the user, ie: `file_usage_add($file, 'module_name', 'user', $element['#entity']->uid);` using an `else` condition if the `nid` is not yet available. Would that be considered an acceptable alternative? Seems it could create problems if the user is deleted later.

Comment: This also works: `file_usage_add($file, 'module_name', 'file', $file->fid);` which seems like the most viable alternative unless there is a smarter approach to processing this image that keeps it bound to the node created.